# Concatenar variables en C++

Tags: c++

Tengo un método que debe retornar `char*` pero no logro concatenar las variables:

```
char* format(char* model){
    char* format;
    format+=day+"";
    return format;
}
```

La variable day es tipo `int`, vengo de java así que aun no logro hacer este procedimiento.

Por ahora model no hace nada porque no puedo ni imprimir `format`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tu objetivo es concatenar variables, usa un [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
std::stringstream ss;

// Concatenar variable en un texto:
int variable = 0;
ss << "Texto " << variable;

// Mostrar resultado por consola
std::cout << ss.str() << '\n';
```

Si tu objetivo es "método que debe retornar `char*`" te diré que no hagas jamás un método así:

1. En C++ es mejor gestionar las cadenas de caracteres con `std::string`, no con punteros a carácter.
2. Si gestionas una cadena de caracteres con punteros a carácter, tendrás que pasar por todo el tedio de gestionar la memoria manualmente.

`1`

```
std::string concatena(const std::string &texto, int valor) {
    return texto + std::to_string(valor);
}
```

`2`

```
char* concatena(const std::string &texto, int valor) {
    auto v = std::to_string(valor);
    char *resultado = new char[v.length() + texto.length() + 1];
    auto p = std::copy(texto.begin(), texto.end(), resultado);
    *p = ' ';
    ++p;
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), p);
    return p;
}

// Si usamos 'concatenar' debemos borrar la memoria manualmente:
auto v = concatenar("Texto ", 0);
// ... usar v ...
delete[] v;
```

Comment: Gracias, es que me pidieron que haga el metodo así

Comment: Si te pidieron hacer el método así, te pidieron algo que no debería hacerse.